# TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not generator

Tags: python, generator, typeerror

Why does the following Python code raise an error
`TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not generator`
while if I comment the first (useless) line in generator f, everything works fine?

```py
from itertools import izip

def z():
    for _ in range(10): 
        yield _

def f(z):
    for _ in z: pass    # if I comment this line it works! (??)
    for x in range(10):
        yield (x,10*x,100*x,1000*x)

iterators =  izip(*f(z))
for it in iterators:
    print list(it)
```

N.B. What I am actually trying to do is, with a single generator, return multiple iterators (as many as I will pass to the generator as arguments). The only way I found to do that is to yield tuples and use izip() on them - black magic to me.

Comment: You might find  `tee` from itertools interesting ...

Comment: `tee` has to run through and store all elements once before it can duplicate the iterator, cf. the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee. Unfortunately there is no magic, and my attempt here was naive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is amusing: you forgot to call `z` when you passed it to `f`:

```
iterators =  izip(*f(z()))
```

So `f` tried to iterate over a function object:

```
for _ in z: pass  # z is a function
```

This raised a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Python innards caught it and reraised with a confusing error message.

```
# ceval.c

static PyObject *
ext_do_call(PyObject *func, PyObject ***pp_stack, int flags, int na, int nk)
{
 ...

            t = PySequence_Tuple(stararg);
            if (t == NULL) {
                if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_TypeError)) {
                    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                                 "%.200s%.200s argument after * "
                                 "must be a sequence, not %200s",
                                 PyEval_GetFuncName(func),
                                 PyEval_GetFuncDesc(func),
                                 stararg->ob_type->tp_name);
 ...
```

Comment: Looks like it was only fixed recently. I was bitten by this in some code that wanted to use `zip(*...)` on a generator that could `raise TypeError`s internally - I had planned for such errors and intended for them to propagate. Looks like I have to build the "zipped" lists manually for now, since I'm still on 3.4 :(